# How to find an average for set of scores and a weight

Tags: linear-algebra, average, means

I have a set of reviews for a product, such that each review has a score [1 - 10] and a year of review submittion. I need to find the average of scores for this product.

The challenging part that I need to give a weight for the reviews' scores depending on their year of submission, such that the newest the highest impact on the final product's score.

When the review is older than 5 years its weight value defaults to 0.5
Otherwise it equals: 1 - (current_year - year_of_review) * 0.1

What is the formula that I can use to find the final product score ?

I found something called "Weighted Mean", is that relevant ?

Comment: @KarnWatcharasupat I am not asking about how to calculate the weight , I already have the formula to calculate it. I need to find the final score considering these weights.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I tried to think about changing the base of sum/count by reducing the count according to the weight, but it seems not reasonable.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos If found this term also "Weighted mean" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean. I am not sure if it is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula for the weight is as good as any.

So if you have $n$ reviews with scores $s_j$ and weights $w_j$, then the weighted review score is

$$S = \frac{\sum_{j=1}^n w_j s_j}{\sum_{j=1}^n w_j}$$

Comment: Seems great, I am going to try it and get back to you. Thanks

Comment: So it is indeed called "weighted mean" ?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean

Comment: That's the one!